# attr('value') is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to get the value attribute of a 5 star rating, however when I hover over it, I get undefined. When I have attr('class') instead of attr('value') however it works. I was wondering if someone could help me out. Thanks.

```
 <fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label> 
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>

</fieldset>
```

Here is the javascript

```
 $(document).on('mouseover', '.rating', function(e) {
       var c = $(e.target).attr('value')
       alert(c);

    });
```

Comment: it doesnt alert anything when I tried that

Answer (score 1):

Change the event listener it is current alerting any mouse over event on the fieldset, if you are only interested in the input tag div's then you want `.rating input` not `.rating`

**Option 1:**

```
 $(document).on('mouseover', '.rating input', function(e) {
       var c = $(e.target).attr('value')
       console.log(c);
       alert(c);
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uexycqxo/2/

**Option 2:**

Another option is using the JQuery `.is` this lets you test the content of the element set and you can keep your original event listener on the `.rating` tag.

```
 $( ".rating" ).on('mouseover', function( event ) {  
  var target = $( event.target );  
  if ( target.is( "input" ) ) {  
      var value = target.attr('value')
      alert(value);
  }  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uexycqxo/3/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have add a listener to wrong element. Class "rating" refers to fieldset not to "input".

A possible correction is adding 'class="rating"' to each input as below:

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.rating', function(e) {
  var c = $(e.target).attr('value')
  alert(c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <input class="rating" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input class="rating" type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="rating" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input class="rating" type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="rating" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input class="rating" type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="rating" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label> 
    <input class="rating" type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input class="rating" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input class="rating" type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score -1):

Someone posted the solution and it worked. However it got deleted for some reason so I'll post what the solution was.

```
$('.rating').on('mouseover', 'label', function(e) {
   console.log($(this).prev().val());


});
```